# Electron-builder build for all architectures, platform, and build types together

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using `ubuntu machine 20.x`. I am using `electron-packager` to build electron apps.

I wish to use Electron-package build for all `architectures`, `platform`, `distributions` types like `zip`, `snap`, `exe`, `msi`, etc. I am trying to use `electron-builder -mwl` command but facing issues.

1. I am gettng warning `"electronbuilder-deps": "electron-builder install-app-deps"`.
2. Second, I wish to only copy some folders into `resources` folder. I want to copy other folders into the main electron.exe root folder. How am I supposed to do it?
3. I am getting random errors like below:

```
    To ensure your native dependencies are always matched electron version, simply add script `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps" to your `package.json`
      • writing effective config  file=dist/builder-effective-config.yaml
      ⨯ /workspace/desktop-cgi/node_modules/iconv-corefoundation/lib/native.node: invalid ELF header  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: /workspace/desktop-cgi/node_modules/iconv-corefoundation/lib/native.node: invalid ELF header
```

I have looked at this however this does not look comprehensive. https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build.html

Here is the `package.json` `build` script I am using:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.example.${name}",
    "asar": true,
    "beforePack": "",
    "afterPack": "",
    "files": [
      "index.js",
      "src/*",
      "src/**/*",
      "binaries/**/*",
      "binaries/**/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources"
    },
    "extraFiles": [
      "credentials"
    ],
    "publish": null,
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "dir",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "deb",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "apk",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "rpm",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "appImage",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "tar.xz",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "zip",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "dir",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "appx",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "msi",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "portable",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "nsisWeb",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "squirrel",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "zip",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "tar.xz",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "dir",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "dmg",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "zip",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "pkg",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "mas",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        },
        {
          "target": "tar.xz",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64",
            "x64",
            "ia32",
            "armv7l",
            "arm64"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```